# IOS app how to do post signup landing page with instructions

Tags: swift

Had no idea how to word this in a search, so I apologize if an answer already exists.  I just finished building my first app.  Its use is pretty intuitive, but nonetheless some basic explanation would be helpful.

I seem to remember certain apps having a landing page you only see right after signup that explain some basic functionality.  Either this or perhaps its on the signup page itself.  Anyways, as a beginner dev what would be the best (and hopefully not super difficult) way to communicate to the user some basic functionality.  I'm not a big app consumer myself, so please tell me where the explanation should go and how I could learn to accomplish this in code.

Comment: If you're asking how to show something only on the first run, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27208103/7214321) answers that. If you're asking about how to communicate something to the user, the [user experience site](http://ux.stackexchange.com) would be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UserDefaults which allows for *persistent* data storage. For example:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if !defaults.bool(forKey: "opened") {
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "opened")
    //present landing page
}
```

Your landing page will probably be in the form of a UIPageViewController.

I hope this helps you out and let me know if you have any trouble!

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is **On Boarding** or **Walkthroughs**. The easiest way to do this is a UIPageViewController.

Visual Examples: [here](https://apptimize.com/blog/2016/02/the-4-best-mobile-user-onboarding-flows-weve-seen-so-far/)

Tutorial: [Swift](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/)