# Find date when app was first installed / downloaded from the App Store

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I'd like to monetise currently free features of my app in future releases. Since I don't want to agitate existing users I want to make sure things stay free for them.

In order to find out whether they had used my app before the new release I'd like to find a way to acquire the date when they first installed the app or downloaded it from the App Store.

I've found this discussion: [Detect first launch of iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208103/detect-first-launch-of-ios-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But it stores the first launch in the user defaults of the app, which to my knowledge, will be wiped once the app is deleted.
My app does not communicate with any online service/data base where I could store such information.

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

If there is another way please point me into the right direction.

Comment: Without having some type of remote storage, I'm not sure it's possible. I'd recommend iCloud or Firebase as free/cheap solutions

Comment: As far as i know KeyChain is not wiped when the app is deleted. But I don't think this is the correct way to go for your needs.

Comment: I don’t think this information is available through any API or within the app. Also, Apple may not like having some users pay for some feature while others continue to use them for free. As far as I am aware, all users need to be able to access the same free or paid features.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. @rmaddy Thanks for marking as duplicate, I'm sorry I didn't find the referenced questions before. I will look into Apple's receipt validation.

Comment: @Chris Apple does seem to tolerate this, I can think of different iOS apps/services that use different programs depending on when the user had downloaded/purchased the app, Songsterr being one, for example. Users that have purchased it years ago for 3 bucks can use it without limitations while new users are limited to subscriptions.

Comment: @Teetz It's been a while since I messed with KeyChain, but I think I stumbled over a decent wrapper recently. Will have a look.

Comment: Ah ok. I didn’t realise that. Thanks