# How to display UIAlert textfield only once after installing APP in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show an alert textfield only when the app is first installed and the first time it runs.

Where should I write any code?

Comment: What should happen second time onwards?

Comment: it is simple so not posting as answer . Keep Bool in user defaults and toggle it when you show it

Comment: First you need to know if is the first time the app was installed/launched, for that refer to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208103/detect-first-launch-of-ios-app and from there, on your first viewController display the alert

Comment: In appdelegagte write the code store a variable inside persistent storage if alert is shown it so simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the information (may be a Bool Flag) in `NSUserDefaults` that whether Alert is shown or not. If not shown then show and set the value accordingly in `NSUserDefaults`

```
let isInfoShown = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Info")
if (isInfoShown == nil || isInfoShown == "")
{
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue("ShownInfo", forKey: "Info")
    // Show Alert  here
}
```

When handled With `Bool` in `UserDefaults`

```
let alertShown = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ShownAlert")
if !alertShown {
    print("1st time launch, showing info Alert.")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ShownAlert")
}
```

**Note** - `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ShownAlert")`, won't return `nil`, but `false` if the value doesn't exist.

**SideNote** - If App is removed/deleted and re-installed then Alert will show again. If App is updated then Alert will not be shown. This is because `UserDefaults` is lost when App is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation. Can I write the above code in AppDelegate?

Comment: You may just wrap over this code where Alert is being shown. //Show Alert here - just put your alert here. If the Alert is in AppDelegate itself, yes you can put it there.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!